# decimal to binary conversion using recursion in MatLab

Tags: matlab, recursion, binary

I am writing a function in Matlab that converts a decimal number to binary and every time I try to run it, it tells me that I am  in a infinite loop. Please help!
This is my function :

```
function y = toBinary(x)
f = 1; 
r=0;
persistent y;

if x==0;
y=0;

else 
r = mod(x,2);
y = y+(r*f);
f = f*10;
y = toBinary (x/2);
end
save toBinary
```

"x" is the decimal number we input;

"y" is the binary output;

"r" is the remainder;

"f" is the factor

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How does `x/2` ever become zero? (hint: what is the `type` of your `x`?)

Comment: dec2bin is built-in. Any reason you can't use that?

Comment: Just freshly solved.  See the duplicate link.  I suspect that you and the other person who asked the same question are classmates.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `toBinary(floor(x/2))`.  Otherwise, you will end up with values after the decimal point.